# Integrating VIs in LabVIEW

Tags: python, labview

I am currently working on a LabVIEW project which consists of 2 VIs(let it be A and B). I want to use output of A as input of the B. I am facing some problems while integrating the 2 VIs the output is an appended array which is also being stored in an empty file(given as input of A) whereas the input of B is a file path. Is there any conversion possible so that the values of appended array can be converted to file path? Can python script be used to automate the project, if yes then how?
[image: Initial circuit]
I tried downloading LabVIEW 2020 but it is neither showing error nor there is any progress in the progress bar. Thus, the snippet attached here is from 2019 version.
[image: Modified block diagram of VI-A]

Comment: you can't use python script, index the array and convert to path from string, use terminal to communicate between two VI's

Comment: A picture is really valuable here... please post a picture of the connector panes of A and B. Feel free to black out the names of the VIs (and the icon if necessary). What I'm looking to see is the data types of the various inputs and outputs. Your text description is not clear enough.

Comment: I have changed the approach a little bit but still it is not working. Attached here are the links of the 2 VIs  [1]: imgur.com/XP4NB0I (circuit of vi -A ) [2]: imgur.com/k84ZSRw (circuit of vi -B)

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how your generated file B and your comparison file A look like?
I assume that you use commas in B so that you compare 3 to 6 values.
Is your error message that the sizes don't match?

Answer (score 2):

I looked over your code.

When I tried your vi A, i got a file with 6 values seperated by a comma because that's my default setting. It looks like this:

> Temperature,Pressure,Humidity
> 3,369,56,019,81,268
> 26,458,16,571,68,245
> 21,902,77,986,20,107
> 56,759,17,852,43,869

If this is the case in your generated file, use %.;%.3f as format for the writeSpreadsheet.vi
This forces the decimal point to be a point instead of a comma.

When I tried the code like this, it worked perfectly fine.

By the way, you don't have to use the flat sequence structure, just use your error wire and connect every vis from the beginning to the end.
Like this:
[image: VI_A]

Additionally you should initialize the array that you shift in your while loop. If you use it one time, it might not be needed but if you call the vi a second time, the values might get stored there and the new values would just get appended.

Feel free to ask if you need more help :)

Here is an example of the .txt file that I have generated with your vi:

> Temperature,Humidity,Pressure
> 38.802,66.355,4.347
> 64.646,68.519,60.982
> 71.997,56.336,96.116
> 20.744,24.189,75.689
> 85.731,25.168,20.026
> 65.386,67.284,97.049

Comment: I tried to make the circuit by using the same approach as yours but couldn't get the output file with the data (the output file is still blank and data is not getting filled) .https://imgur.com/VBZuo9p  Can you please provide the vi for the same so that I can check my circuit error.

Comment: You use the exact same vi that I used in this answer... I just tested it, for me it works perfectly fine...
I even tried to use a file as path input that didn't exist to this point, this also works...

Does your generated file not exist or is it just empty?

Comment: The file generated at the end i.e after the second for loop is empty(although the circuit was working perfectly fine until the generation of numbers). Also I was trying to use your code snippet but it gave an error message -  https://imgur.com/cYX6EUC

Comment: Oh, now I get it. I use the 2020 Community Edition which is newer than the version of 2019 that you are probably using. It seems to have some compatibility problems. Please try to copy the code in your LabVIEW Version manually, then it should work

Comment: Already tried to do that too, still not working. Can you please tell me about the connections made in the "Error frame" . I am not sure if I am making them correctly or not.

Comment: I will convert my vi to 2019 later and post an update to my answer with the .png . 

In the "Error" case I just connected input and output.This way, if an error has occurred previously, processing of this vi is skipped.

Comment: I have tried to make the circuit in exactly the same way as yours. Also I am trying to download 2020, if it gets installed and vi runs without any error I will let you know. Otherwise, I will try the vi you'll make using 2019. Thank you in advance for helping:)

Comment: Do you have any error messages this time? Sadly, i can only upload a picture, but the onyl .png that can be generated, is this with the 2020 version.
Can you please try to make a .png snippet and add it to your question? I can open it on my PC and maybe find what's wrong :)
To do so, select all of your code in the Block Diagram, and click on "Edit" in the menu bar, there you find "Create VI Snippet from Selection". Click on it, then you can save the .png.  To insert it correctly, just add it as image

Comment: I tested your version, it works perfectly fine for me... I can generate the .txt file without any problem. I put an example in my answer... Sorry, but I really can't think of anything else that could cause the problem...

Comment: You could try to debug with "Retain Wire Values" and "Higlight Execution". Does the array contain any values when it leaves the loops?
If yes, maybe you should check and make sure, your path is valid, you generate a txt file and you open the correct file to see the result. :)

Comment: I don't know what the exact error was but just now I made few connections again and finally it worked!! Thank you so much for resolving my doubts and helping me out :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it works now :) 
I would greatly appreciate it, if you could accept my answer.
Have a nice day and have fun with LabView :D